# C storing string literals inside dynamic 2D arrays

Tags: c, string-literals

I have functions that are dynamically allocating memories to store strings into `char ***` (a 2D array of strings or 3D array of chars).

I later thought that It would be better if I stored them as string literals, so I changed my array to `const char ***`. This, however, is giving me errors when I'm using `strcpy()` and `free()`.

```
error: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type
```

I understand that the parameters `strcpy()` and `free()` take are of the type `char *` and `void *`, but I have also read that it is good practice to store strings into `const char *` instead of `char *`.

How I am suppose to use string literals if it can't be used for operations like `strcpy()` or `free()`? Should I have just left it as `char ***` instead of `const char ***`? There's something obvious here I'm not understanding.

Comment: Neither an object of type `char ***` nor the object, if any, to which it points is a 2D array of strings or a 3D array of `char`, and those are themselves distinct from each other.  More generally, arrays and pointers are not at all the same thing, and multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays, not arrays of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have understood your array does not contain pointers to string literals but instead it contains copies of string literals. Otherwise what is strcpy used for?  So you may remove the const qualifier from the array (or corresponding pointer)  declaration. Take into account that in C string literals have types of non-constant arrays.

Comment: if, say I wanted to use `const char ***`, should I not use `strcpy()` but directly assign the string literal? e.g. `const char *a = "foo"; const char *b = a`? And does one free string literals (`const char *`)?

Comment: @thestateofmay If you want to store pointers to string literals then you can use the qualifier const.  String literals have static storage duration.

Comment: @thestateofmay one frees only objects that one has dynamically allocated.  String literals are not dynamically allocated (which is conveyed by Vlad's remark that they have static storage duration, but I'm uncertain whether you recognize that).